# Excessive network usage after restart

Tags: networking

I've noticed this for a while, and cant figure out for the life of me what is happening here. I've looked around on the internet and didn't find anything releated to this, so here I am.

I am using the gnome system monitor and recently stumbled upon the network history. After taking a quick look at it, I quickly noticed something: There is always some traffic, despite autostart being clear and everything closed / the system restarting. I know there is supposed to be some traffic within the network, but 20 mib sent like 5 minutes after starting the system is a bit excessive. Does anyone know what's up with this?

Comment: 20 mib is not a lot.

Comment: Install `iftop` and then run it with `sudo iftop` and it may tell you where it's going.